# While building a predictive model,Should i ignore the variables having high skewness?

Tags: neural-network, data-mining, decision-tree, prediction

I am trying to build a predictive model using NN/Decision Tree. I have a huge set of variables, so i am trying to do feature selection(removing unwanted variables).Can i remove the variables having high skewness(Not normally distributed)?will it have an impact on the model built?

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is skewed that does not mean it is bad.

Normal distributed data could be just random values, too.

But for many method, you need to spend more time preprocessing skewed variables for *best* performance. But what makes you think it is a good idea to leave them out just because they are skewed?

Comment: Hi,i am just a newbie trying to understand the data mining process.In my case,i have an object(not a target object),the value of the object for 70% of data is 0.so leaving/ignoring this object will affect my model?

Comment: That, too, is common. For example in text. The term is "sparse data". If you'd ignore these attributes in text mining, you would have no data left.